# SQLAlchemy: Load cascading relationships in fewest number of queries (N+1 problem)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relational-database

In reading through SQLAlchemy's documentation, I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem:

I have a very basic database model, with a Parent entity that has a one-to-many relationship with a Child entity, which in turn has a one-to-many relationship with a Grandchild entity. These relationships are defined using SQLAlchemy's default lazy-load behavior, because 99% of the time it makes sense for the loading of these relationships to be deferred.

However, in that other 1% of the time, an expensive operation needs to happen on a Parent instance which requires loading all of its children and grandchildren. I would like to do this in as few queries as possible, ideally only 2:

```
SELECT * FROM child WHERE parent_id=<>
SELECT * FROM grandchild WHERE child_id IN (<>)
```

I know how to do this when I'm building a Query statement from scratch, by chaining together multiple selectinload functions to Query.options:

```
parent = session.query(Parent).options(
    selectinload(Parent.children).selectinload(Child.grandchildren)
).get(parent_id)
```

However, if I already have the Parent instance loaded into memory, how can I trigger the loading of its Parent.children relationship & Child.grandchildren relationships in the same way as the above query? Sort of like a way to temporarily override the relationship's defined loader strategy, or a way to specify the Query.options(...) method above, but without creating a Query statement, because my starting point is an already-loaded Parent instance, not a parent_id.

Comment: Have you tried using third party packages? ( [sqlalchemy-orm-tree](https://sqlalchemy-orm-tree.readthedocs.io/installation.html) ). or [materialized_paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/_modules/examples/materialized_paths/materialized_paths.html). Looks like what you need.

Comment: Those packages seem very specific to tree models. Ignore the fact that my example happens to have a tree structure -- what I'm looking for is a generalized solution to the N+1 problem for recursively loading one-to-many relationships. The selectinload() function already solves this problem when building a Query object from scratch, but how to achieve the same behaviour when loading relationships from a root object?

Comment: I understand. hm...  not sure there is an easy(or `sqlalchemy`) solution. 

you can do this trick using 1 query +  `path` ( just an example: `session.query(Table).filter(Table.path.startswith('{PARENT_ID_HERE}.')).all()` ) but in this case you'll work with unstructured models. Otherwise you need to know `child_ids`.